# Spring specify the correct bean references as factory method arguments

Tags: spring-mvc

How can specify the correct bean refrences, When I using Abstrarct factory method pattern with Spring.

I get constructor arguments errors on the Spring `dispatcher-servlet.xml`.

the errors:

> Ambiguous factory method argument types - did you specify the correct bean references as factory method arguments?

short dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<bean id="myFactory" class="cwsei.spring.dao.CategoryFactory" factory-method="findCategory">
<constructor-arg type="java.lang.Enum" value="${categoryType}" />
</bean>
```

Here is my code:

```
public abstract class Category {
public abstract List list(int departId);
..
}
public class CategoryFactory {

public enum CategoryType { firstclass,secondClass,...}

public static Category findCategory(CategoryType categoryType) {
...
}
}
```

Thanks,
mkohan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your findCategory factory takes a given enum, then Spring does it all for you.

e.g

```
public class enum X { A, B }
public CategoryFactory findCategory( X someX )
```

now in Spring

```
<constructor-arg value="A" />
```

Comment: I don't want initiate a value for argument. I want the Abstract factory method passes that value on run time. Do I have to initiate a value for argument?

Comment: All of Spring is at runtime.  I suspect your referring to the variable substitution, just remove the type attribute from the constructor-arg tag.

Comment: I changed to this: <constructor-arg  value="${CategoryType}"  />
I got this errors:Error creating bean with name 'myFactory' defined in ServletContext resource : Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type[CategoryFactory$CategoryType]: Could not convert factory method argument value of type[java.lang.String] to required type [CategoryFactory$CategoryType]: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type'CategoryFactory$CategoryType';

Answer (score 1):

1. Lazy initialize the bean if possible
2. If you want to use a factory-method and without passing any constructor arguments in the bean configuration, use

   ```
   <constructor-arg><null/></constructor-arg>
   ```

   to specify null arguments